# Unable to cast object of type System.Int32 to System.Object[] when calling generic method with parameters via reflection

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, invoke

Les't say I have some class with two constructors (without parameters and with them):

```
public class Employee
{
    private int Salary = 0;

    public Employee()
    {
        Salary = 100;
    }

    public Employee(int newSalary)
    {
        Salary = newSalary;
    }
}
```

And I have some static helper class that have generic methods to call constructors:

```
public static class GenericClassCreator
{
    public static T CreateClassNoParams<T>()
        where T : class, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    public static T CreateClassWithParams<T>(params object[] args)
        where T : class
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
    }
}
```

Lets assume I have Type of class that I need to construct (**typeof(Employee)** in this particular case) and call it's constructor with the following code:

```
var method1 = typeof(GenericClassCreator).GetMethod("CreateClassNoParams");
var generic1 = method1.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Employee));

var employee1 = generic1.Invoke(null, null);


var method2 = typeof(GenericClassCreator).GetMethod("CreateClassWithParams");
var generic2 = method2.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Employee));

var employee2 = generic2.Invoke(null, new object[] { (object)500 });
```

Obtaining employee1 (via constructor without parameters) is ok. But obtaining employee2 (via constructor with parameter) throws exception:

> Unable to cast object of type System.Int32 to System.Object[]

Even if I change

```
generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { (object)500 });
```

to

```
generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { new object() });
```

exception is thrown

> Unable to cast object of type System.Object to System.Object[]

So what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is expecting an `object[]` as parameter. `MethodInfo.Invoke` expects an `object[]` containing all the parameters. This means that you need an `object[]` containing another `object[]`:

```
var employee2 = generic2.Invoke(null, new object[] { new object[] { 500 } });
```

Comment: Oh..  `object[]` containing another `object[]` - thats really confusing :). Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The part that confuses you is this: `Invoke` requires an object array for the parameters of the method you invoke. Now it takes that object array, and uses the values in it to call the method.

However, your method itself also requires an `object[]` to work. Now the outer `object[]` is no longer there, there is just an `int` to call your method. You have to wrap the first array with a second one to comply to your method signature.

```
generic2.Invoke(null, new object[] { new object[] { (object)500 } });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This
generic2.Invoke(null, new object[] { new object[] { 500 } });